# Weak* convergence on $C_{0}(X)$ where $X$ is a locally compact metric space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally compact metric space and let $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $X$ which has no convergent subsequence. Show that $\{n^{-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{x_{k}}\}$ converges to 0 in the weak* topology on $C_{0}(X)*$, where $\delta_{x_{k}}$ denotes the point mass at $x_{k}$.

By Riesz-Representation of $C_{0}(X)$, I know the dual of it is the complex measure space on $X$. But I fail to connect it to $x_{k}$ is a sequence in $X$ which has no convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that if $f\in C_0(X)$ you have $\lim_n f(x_n) = 0$.  (Because for each small $\epsilon$  there is  a compact neighborhood of off of which $|f|<\epsilon$, and only finitely many of the $x_n$ are in that neighborhood.) Which is to say, $\langle \delta_n,f\rangle\to0$. Then, by the fact that the Cesàro limit of a sequence with limit $L$ is also $L$,  we have  $\lim_n \langle\mu_n,f\rangle=0$, where $\mu_n=(1/n)\sum_1^n \delta_{x_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in C_0(X)$. We claim that $f(x_n) \to 0$. Suppose this is not true. Then there exists $a>0$ such that $|f(x_n) | > a$ for infinitely many values of $n$, say $n=n_k, k=1,2,...$ with $n_1<n_2<...$. Now $f \in C_0(X)$ implies that there is a compact set $K$ such that $|f(y)| <a$ for all $y \in X\setminus K$. It follows that $x_{n_k} \in K$ for all $k$. But then $\{x_n\}$ has  convergent subsequence. We have proved that $f(x_n) \to 0$ which implies that $\int f d\mu_n \to 0$ where $\mu =\frac 1 n \sum_1^{n}\delta_{x_k}$